# Несколько spl_autoload_register();

Tags: php

Вообщем у меня несколько

```
spl_autoload_register();
```

Беда в том, что оба они не работают, в чем может быть загвоздка?
Один подгружает классы из ядра, второй загружает классы шаблонизатора.

Но всегда срабатывает тот который находится первым. Как лечить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но всегда срабатывает тот который находится первым.

Всегда срабатывает весь стек загрузчиков по порядку, переход к следующему осуществляется до тех пор, пока класс не найден и не загружен (а что, могли быть варианты?)

> Как лечить?

Каждый автозагрузчик должен уметь не нервничать и спокйно реагировать на отсутствие файла, в котором может быть класс. В этом случае управление просто перейдет к следующему загрузчику, ответственность текущего кончается, и за остальное он беспокоиться не должен. Впрочем, использование PSR-0/PSR-4 настолько же спокойно унифицирует загрузчик и позволяет иметь всего один загрузчик в системе, а если предоставить эту задачу composer, то можно решить проблемы с автозагрузкой даже для пакетов, которые ничего не знают про PSR.

Comment: 1. Не заметно что то :)

Comment: @rnddev, не зпметно что?

Comment: Есть еще Zend Autoload, есть компосер по какой то причине не поиспользовать (ну например на хостинге нет гита)